# Changing textLabel to change at a specific time

Tags: iphone, xcode

Im trying to make the the textLabel change at 12am every 24 hours anyone help me with setting up this code?

This is the current code I am using.

h fil

```
NSTimer *timer;

IBOutlet UILabel *textLabel;
```

m file

```
(void)onTimer {
static int i = 0;

if ( i == 0 ) { textLabel.text = @"iphone app"; }

else if ( i == 1 ) { textLabel.text = @" Great App!"; }

else if ( i == 2 ) { textLabel.text = @" WOW!"; }

else { textLabel.text = @" great application again!!"; i = -1; }

i++; }

timer =[NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:5.0 target:self selector:@selector(onTimer) userInfo:nil repeats:YES];
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using this code:

```
NSDate *date = [NSDate date]; //current date

NSTimeInterval secondsInDay = 24 * 60 * 60;

NSCalendar *calendar = [NSCalendar currentCalendar];

NSDateComponents *components = [calendar components:(NSYearCalendarUnit | NSMonthCalendarUnit | NSDayCalendarUnit) fromDate:date];
if([components hour] >= 12) {
    //set next day - by adding 24 hours to current day
    NSDate *nextDay = [NSDate dateWithTimeInterval:secondsInDay sinceDate:date];
    //recalculate components
    components = [calendar components:(NSYearCalendarUnit | NSMonthCalendarUnit | NSDayCalendarUnit) fromDate:nextDay];
} 

NSDateComponents *newDateComponents = [[NSDateComponents alloc] init];
[newDateComponents setYear:[components year]];
[newDateComponents setMonth:[components month]];
[newDateComponents setDay:[components day]];
[newDateComponents setHour:12];
[newDateComponents setMinute:0];
[newDateComponents setSecond:0];

NSDate *firingDate = [calendar dateFromComponents:newDateComponents];
[newDateComponents release];

NSTimer *timer = [[NSTimer alloc] initWithFireDate:firingDate interval:secondsInDay target:self selector:@selector(onTimer:) userInfo:nil repeats:YES];
[[NSRunLoop mainRunLoop] addTimer:timer forMode:NSDefaultRunLoopMode];
[timer release];
```

Then implement onTimer method:

```
- (void) onTimer:(NSTimer)timer {
   self.textLabel.text = @"Greetings from Poland"; //;)
}
```